# How to use SpEL as param of a custom annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Say I have a custom annotation @MyAnnotion with a param 'value', I want this param value read from property file like this:

```
@MyAnnotion(value = "${some.prop}")
public String controllerMethod() {
  return "";
}
```

now the value I got is the raw string but not the real value in propterty file.
how can I got the value in property file?

Comment: You have to parse it yourself. That is also how it works internally in Spring.

Comment: Can you please post some code behind that annotation? How you are processing `@MyAnnotation` ?

Comment: the code behind the annotation is to disable(or enable) a @RequestMapping method according the value of the  param , which is supposed to be read from properties file